# add a header to all responses in snap framework

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

The title sums it up. I want add a header to all my responses in snap. 
I can add a modifyRequest handler for each of my routes like :

```
apiRoutes :: [(ByteString, Handler b Api ())]
apiRoutes = [("status",  addHeader)]


addHeader :: Handler b Api ()
addHeader = do
   modifyResponse (setHeader "Content-Type" "application/json")
   otherHandler

otherHandler :: Handler b Api ()
otherHandler = metod Get doActualStuff <|> metod Get doMoreActualStuff
```

Now if I have 100 different routes and I want to add the header to them all. I have to write an intercepter function for all those routes. and if I want to change the header I must modify all 100 intercepter functions.

Is there a short simple way ?

Comment: This seems pretty short and simple to me. What exactly is the problem with this approach?

Comment: @jkeuhlen let's say I have 100 different routes and I want to add the header to them all. I have to write an intercepter function for all those routes. and if I want to change the header I must modify all 100 functions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with snap, but can't you just define `apiRoutes = map (second (modifyResponse … *>)) [("status", otherHandler)]`?

Comment: @sjakobi sounds like an excelenet idea. I will try it out.

Comment: @sjakobi I fugured it out with your hint. I sometimes completely forget about the tools that haskell provide. Thank you

Comment: @miladzahedi If you figured out the problem on your own, you should write up (and accept) your own answer. That way people in the future with this problem can see what your solution was.

Comment: @jkeuhlen Ok, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the hint that sjakobi provided I figured it out. This can be done like:

```
apiRoutes :: [(ByteString, Handler b Api ())]
apiRoutes = map (mapSecond (addHeaders >>))
[("status",  addHeader)]


addHeaders :: Handler b Api ()
addHeaders = do
   modifyResponse (setHeader "Content-Type" "application/json")
   modifyResponse (setHeader "more-header" "more-header")

mapSecond :: (b -> c) -> (a,b) -> (a,c)
mapSecond f (a,b) = (a,f b)
```